# IntelliJ and JPA Controller Class

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

IntelliJ has a built in JPA Class generator but it only generates entities.

Does it have a generator for entity controller class like in NetBeans and Eclipse's TeloSys Tools ?

Comment: The same question has been asked here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206280429-JPA-controller-genereation-howTO- You might want to vote it up to get some attention.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CLI (Command Line Interface) version of the **Telosys Code Generator**

See https://www.telosys.org/cli.html  and  https://doc.telosys.org/telosys-cli

This tool can be used in association with any kind of IDE (IntelliJ, NetBeans, VSCode, Atom, etc )

You just have to define where to generate the files (the 'destination folder' in the configuration file)

You can reuse existing templates (you can also create your own templates if necessary)